# TikZ fitting library confused by transform shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit

It seems that the fit library misses a bit when using with `transform shape`:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw] (b) at (1,1) {B};
    \node[draw] (c) at (-1,1) {C};
    \node[draw, red, fit =(a) (b) (c)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, transform shape]
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw] (b) at (1,1) {B};
    \node[draw] (c) at (-1,1) {C};
    \node[draw, red, fit =(a) (b) (c)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in (version 3.0.1a, shipped with Ubuntu 18.04LTS)

[image: output with unaligned nodes]

Is this normal? Is it possible to circumvent it, short of manually adjust `inner sep`?

Comment: Your example works fine for me. Is your install up to date ?

Comment: ...and it works for 3.1.3. So it's fixed. Should I delete the question or is it useful to leave it here with a mini-answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resulted that the problem was fixed in version `3.1.3`, which resulted in the correct behavior.

Still, the problem **seems** to come back if you use `rotate`, as noticed by [@Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schr%C3%B6dingers-cat) in comment (now deleted):

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw] (b) at (1,1) {B};
    \node[draw] (c) at (-1,1) {C};
    \node[draw, red, fit =(a) (b) (c), inner sep=0pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, rotate=45, transform shape]
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw] (b) at (1,1) {B};
    \node[draw] (c) at (-1,1) {C};
    \node[draw, red, fit =(a) (b) (c), inner sep=0pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...although this should be expected, given that the manual states that `fit` takes into account only north, south, east and west anchors. The behavior can be fixed with:

```latex
\node[draw, red, fit =(a) (b) (c)
            (a.north west) (a.south west) (a.south east) (a.north east)
            (b.north west) (b.south west) (b.south east) (b.north east)
            (c.north west) (c.south west) (c.south east) (c.north east),
            inner sep=0pt]{};
```

which gives:

[image]